# Dropdown isn't closed when click outside of it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide the `dropdown menu` when is clicked outside, but no success so far.

I've read about 10 or more threads here and tried different solutions.

This is the `dropdown menu` that I have

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Per Page</button>
  <div id="openmenu" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="">15</a>
    <a href="">20</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the showing part

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("openmenu").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

I've tried this so far

Try 1:

```
function boxCloser(e){
  if(e.target.id != 'openmenu'){
     document.body.removeEventListener('click', boxCloser, false);
     $('.dropdown-content').hide();
  }
}
```

Try 2:

```
$(document).on("click touchend", function(){
    $(".dropdown-content").removeClass("open");
});
```

Try 3:

```
$('body').not(".dropdown").off('click').on('click',function(){$(".dropdown").removeClass("show")});
```

and try 4

```
function hideDiv(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0].classList.remove('hidden');
}

document.addEventListener("click", hideDiv, false);
```

None of them close the menu when I click outside the `dropdown` part.

Comment: Can you add your CSS too, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have jQuery included as some of the question examples use it. The 'isMenuOpen' variable would have to be set to true when opening the menu. Though it is not strictly necessary and you can omit it.

working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3ut2yqj1/

```
<button id="open_menu"> open menu </button>    
<div id="menu" style="border: 1px solid black; width:100px; height:100px; display:none"> </div>

 var isMenuOpen= false;

 $("#open_menu").on('click',function()
 {
   isMenuOpen = true;
   $("#menu").show();
 });

  $(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if (($(e.target).closest('#menu').length == 0) && ($(e.target).closest('#open_menu').length == 0)) {
      if (isMenuOpen == true) {
        isMenuOpen = false;
        $("#menu").hide();
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have jQuery as an option, the following code is more suited as it will support multiple dropdowns (it isn't dependent upon the ID of the elements involved).

You need to stop the event propagating up the DOM when you click on the button, and then assign a `click` handler to `document`. This is achieved by returning `false` from the click handler on the button.

Please see the working demo below:

```js
$(document).on("click touchend", function(e){
  $(".dropdown-content").removeClass("show");
});

$('.dropdown-content').prev('button').on('click', function(e) {  
  $(this).siblings('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button>Per Page</button>
  <div id="openmenu" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="">15</a>
    <a href="">20</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This probably will be the best solution for me because I have multiple dropdowns but I can't get this work. Nothing in the console either ..

Comment: Probably because of the cache but now I've got the error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: Either jQuery is not installed, or it is conflicting with another library. Without seeing the full code you're working from, I'm afraid I can't help.

Comment: It was because the jquery is included after the code above. When I put it after the jquery library I don't get the error anymore but doesn't close on click outside.

Comment: Provide your CSS code. Make sure it doesn't contain `#openmenu` selector which could override styles given by @BenM

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're puzzled with class names of your elements.
In different attempts you provided you use either `openmenu` ID, or `dropdown-content` class, or `dropdown` class for selecting the element, as well as different methods for hiding and showing the dropdown (`show`, `hidden`, `open` classes, etc.)

To fully answer your question one would need to see the corresponding CSS code: what styles do you use for showing and hiding dropdown? Also, how do you bind that `boxCloser()` function to some user event?

Anyway, assuming that you're able to open the dropdown, and the problem is only when closing it, try the following.

#### 1. Update HTML

Update HTML of the button: remove `onclick` attribute and add a class name to it

```html
<button class="dropdown-button">Per Page</button>
```

#### 2. Use the following script (instead of yours)

```
  function onClick(event) {
    // if clicked on .dropdown-button, find .dropdown-content near it and toggle it
    if (event.target.classList.contains("dropdown-button")) {
      var content = event.target.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0];
      if (content)
        content.classList.toggle("show");
    } else if (!event.target.matches(".dropdown *")) {
      // if clicked outside of dropdown, hide all dropdowns
      var allDropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      for (var i = 0; i < allDropdowns.length; i++)
        allDropdowns[i].classList.remove("show");
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

#### 3. Update CSS

I don't know what your CSS is, so make sure you do not refer to `#openmenu` element by ID and use class name instead:

```css
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
  }
  .dropdown-content.show {
    display: block;
  }
```

This should also work for multiple dropdowns and **without jQuery**.

If you want to use jQuery, the script can be simplified:

```
  function onClick(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is(".dropdown-button"))
      $(event.target).parent().find(".dropdown-content").toggleClass("show");
    else if ($(event.target).closest(".dropdown").length === 0)
      $(".dropdown-content").removeClass("show");
  }

  $(document).click(onClick);
```

Note that this code prevents dropdowns from hiding when you click inside of open dropdowns. It also allows multiple dropdowns to be opened simultaneously. You can modify the code to achieve the other behavior in these aspects, but it's outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, the dropdown is fully working it is open when I click on it and it is closing when I click on it. Doesn't close when I click off it. I've tried your code but the menu isn't opened at all with it.

Comment: @Jordan, oh, since you bind the function via `onclick` attribute (which is also not the best practice), update your HTML button like this: `<button onclick="myFunction(event)">Per Page</button>`

Comment: Still, the menu doesn't opening.

Comment: @Jordan, ok, let's go the other way. I extended my answer above for multiple dropdowns and jQuery, tested myself and it should work. If it still doesn't, please provide all HTML, JS and CSS code relevant to the question.
Again, make sure you don't have any "#openmenu" selector in your CSS code

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on("click", function(event){

        var $trigger = $(".dropdown");

        if($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length){

            $(".dropdown-content").slideUp("fast");

        }            

    });
```

try this